# DC motor that drives a flywheel and a DC generator simultaneously

Tags: dc-motor

I have a project that I am analyzing a DC motor that drives simultaneously a flywheel (rotational inertia) and a DC generator. My doubt is, when I am creating the mathematical model of it, I would have the regular open loop DC motor transfer function and this is going to the DC generator? Also, the DC generator used is just another DC motor that it is acting as a generator. I am finding this quite confusing. Could anybody give me a hint?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Why are you creating a mathematical model? The rotational intertia will require torque from the motor to speed it up, and will deliver torque to the generator as it tries to slow it down.

Answer (score 2):

The mathematics of mechanical systems and electrical systems are analogous. If you think of force as voltage and velocity as current, then mass (inertia) becomes equivalent to inductance.

Does this help at all?

Comment: What is equivalent to capacitance? Is it a spring?

Comment: @HarrySvensson: yes.

Comment: @Harry Or balloon pressure, or water height in a vessel, or a flywheel and so on. Had a course in school early in my EE career about SPICE and that it was one of if not the first civilian use of computers and engineers from other fields had to recompute for example water height into F and inertia of moving water in a pipe into H.

Comment: @winny: No, if you think of flywheel=capacitor, then you need to swap the analogies for voltage and current: velocity becomes voltage and force becomes current.

Comment: Ah, and then a spring becomes an inductor (if a flywheel=capacitor, velocity = volt, force = current). So there's many ways to model a mechanical system. This is very cool.

Comment: @David, sorry about that. Balloon or spring it is.

Comment: @HarrySvensson: Yes, it is very cool. Working out the details of these symmetries and analogies can really help strengthen the understanding of the relationship between the math and the real-world phenomena.